# Не компилируется microsip

Tags: c++

Сырцы беру [отсюда](https://www.microsip.org/source) там уже лежит полный проект скомпилировал на visual studio 2017 с SDK 8.1. Выдает единственную ошибку: несовместимые параметры командной строки "/O2" и "/RTC1". Пробовал в свойствах проекта c/c++/общие/формат отладочной информации менять не помогло. Что делать?

Comment: Уберите `/RTC1`.

Comment: @VTT нашел параметры командной строки, только они не изменяемые. Подскажи как их менять то?

Comment: Описание параметров и где они настраиваются можно посмотреть в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/rtc-run-time-error-checks).